# How to change mouse cursor when using SelectionArea in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

So I want my whole screen's text widgets to be selectable and I did it by using SelectionArea. The problem is that I don't want to apply the text cursor implemented since there are texts on my screen where I already applied mouseregion to give it a pointer for the user to know it's clickable.

Anyone has idea how to maintain the default cursors across the screen by still maintaining the feature of SelectionArea?

Can't find any possible solutions for now and I'm new to flutter as well so I am not yet knowledgeable in making advance level configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to achieve this: a. Wrap the Entire View:
Wrap your entire screen (or relevant part) in a MouseRegion.
Set the desired cursor using the cursor property.
Example:
Dart

```
MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click, // Set your desired cursor
  child: YourEntireScreenWidget(),
)
```

Review and use carefully.
b. Custom Cursor Handling:
Use MouseRegion around individual clickable widgets where you want custom cursors.
For other widgets, let the default cursor behavior apply.
Example:

```
MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click, // Custom cursor for specific widget
  child: YourClickableWidget(),
)
```

Review and use carefully.
c. Use MouseCursor.defer:
Set the cursor to MouseCursor.defer to defer cursor choice to the next region behind it.
Example:

```
MouseRegion(
  cursor: MouseCursor.defer, // Defer cursor choice
  child: YourSelectableWidget(),
)
```

Comment: Sorry but none of these help with my problem. I need to get rid of the default text cursor that the SelectionArea gives when using that widget and maintain the cursors I set in each widget I have implemented with mouseregion. Thanks.